# What is the meaning of "full force" in a contract?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

What is the meaning of "full force"? Here is an example of it used bellow. Does it still have the same meaning if "full force" is removed?

> The unenforceability of any provisions of this Lease will not affect
>   the forceability of any other provision of this Lease.  Such other
>   provisions remain in **full force** and effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to state in a contract that if one part is found unenforceable, the rest still is?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6272/is-it-necessary-to-state-in-a-contract-that-if-one-part-is-found-unenforceable)

Comment: @Terry how's that a duplicate?