# Did I lose possession of my goods?

Tags: france, repossession

I live in France.

3 months ago, I was living with someone, in their flat, and I had to buy some piece of furniture (for about 700 euros).

About 2 months ago, I had to leave this place because we couldn't stand the other people presence any longer. At that time, as I had nowhere else to store the piece of furniture I bought, we agreed with this other person that I could leave them at his place, while I was seeking for a new place of my own.

Some week after this, I encountered this person again, and I have been asked if they could refund me the price of the furnitures spanning 2 years, regarding monthly payment, to which I agreed orally.

Fast forwarding today, I never received any money from this person, and last time I saw them, they told me I couldn't have my good back, because now they're theirs and that they won't refund me at all, neither give me my goods back.

Can I do something about it, or did I really lose property on the goods ?

Comment: You now have a contract with them. You can't have the goods but you can have the money. Go to small claims court and hold the person to account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did I lose possession of my goods?

That seems unlikely. But enforcing it sounds complicated, at least from the standpoint of substantive law (the [*Code civil*](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721)). I am not knowledgeable of French procedural law. The difficulty begins with identifying whether your claim is cognizable as *unjust enrichment*, or --per your subsequent oral agreement-- *breach of contract*.

You might want to read sections "*The French Law of Unjust Enrichment*" and "*Enrichissement sans Cause*" in [this post](https://lawexplores.com/6-public-body-unjust-enrichment-claims-in-france-lessons-for-england-and-wales/). Please note that the French Civil Code recently underwent significant reforms, whence references of its articles are likely outdated. Here I pointed out [one example of statutory renumbering](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/39130/if-a-contract-sometimes-uses-the-wrong-name-is-it-still-valid/39132#comment71978_39178) in the Code.

In the second link, you will read that

> originally [...] the action in *enrichissement sans cause* would not
>   be available to the claimant if he or she had any other cause of
>   action, even if that cause of action was blocked for some reason.
>   [...] [B]ut it is perhaps here that the law has relaxed most in recent
>   cases.

Thus, the subtleties of your matter can be decisive for identifying the type of claim that is applicable to your situation.

Lastly, according to [this treatise](https://digitalcommons.law.uga.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1010&context=stu_llm) (on p.54), "*[t]he French legal system does not have the principle of [reasonable] reliance as it exists in the American legal system*" (brackets added). That makes it easier for a plaintiff to prove his claims under French law.

Comment: The questioner says he traded away ownership of the item in return for a payment promise. He essentially sold the item to the other party. So, yes he did lose possession of his sofa. Now it should be an issue of collecting payment.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite "*Now it should be an issue of collecting payment*". Not necessarily. The OP also may opt to *rescind* the contract pursuant to [Article 1224](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=75F9BEA092F1788AC2D3EBC8FF9B1E11.tplgfr23s_3?idArticle=LEGIARTI000032041482&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721&dateTexte=20190420) of the *Code civil*. Furthermore, a contract theory would require the assumptions that (1) the factual prior circumstances do not pre-empt or nullify the formation of such contract, and (2) the OP is able to prove the formation of that *oral* contract.

Answer (score -3):

Judge Judy most likely would ask you:

- how long did you stay together?
- which expenses did you share during that period?
- how much rent did you pay?
- how much did you pay for utility bills?
- did you have agreement to share residence's accommodations?
  after answring these questions you might find yourself even owing substantial amount of € to other tenants...hahahaaaaa